# High-security shredder that doesn't depend on optical sensors

Tags: home-electronics

I've had a couple of shredders in the past, [this AmazonBasics one](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B000S6I9BI/ref=pe_385721_51767431_TE_dp_1) being the most recent. They both broke, and as far as I can tell for the same reason: The optical sensor died. This means that the shredder mechanism works perfectly, except it can't tell that a paper is being pushed in the hole, and therefore it never activates the engine.

I've had some luck with cleaning the optical sensor using an alcohol pad, but that doesn't always work.

I'm sick of this problem. I want a shredder that:

1. Is not dependent on an optical sensor. It's okay for it to have one, as long as there's a manual override, so the shredder doesn't go to the trash if the sensor is broken.
2. Is high-security. None of those long paper strips that can be reassembled into a document. I believe that [level 4](https://www.the-shredder-warehouse.com/security-level) is reasonable.
3. Supports a 220 volt power connection.
4. Is not too expensive hopefully.

Does anyone know of a shredder that meets these criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

63 quid gets you [this P4-level 220VAC](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Bonsaii-12-Sheet-60-Minute-Continuous-Operation/dp/B07G2WMKWG/) shredder. Sadly, Big River Trading Company's website detected my Americanese dialect and would not allow me to ask *Is the paper input sensor mechanical or optical?*